# alternate background-colors between Div Labels

Tags: html, css

I have a table like structure made out of divs.

I want to alternate the background-color of only the divLabels.

Each divrow of a table has a divlabel and a divdata element.

this is what I have tried so far:-

http://jsfiddle.net/o5dv4qkc/

unfortunately, the color of the labels do not alternate, instead show the same color mentioned for the odd rows only:-

```
.About_RowLabel:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #DEF3CA;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not work with my div elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not selecting properly the children: move up by one level to their parents, and start from there, like `.someParentClass:nth-of-type(even) .child{}`: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o5dv4qkc/3/)

```css
.About_Row {
  height: 2em;
  width: 500px;
  /*float:left;*/
}
.About_RowLabel {
  width: 98px;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  background-color: #71cd7b;
}
.About_RowData {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.About_Row:nth-of-type(odd) .About_RowLabel {
  background-color: #DEF3CA;
}
.serv_resize {
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  color: #444;
  width: 425px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 239px;
}
```

```html
<div id="you" class="serv_resize">
  <div class="About_Row">
    <div class="About_RowLabel">
      BirthDate:
    </div>
    <div class="About_RowData">
      <asp:Label ID="lblDoB" runat="server" Text="DoB"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="About_Row">
    <div class="About_RowLabel">
      As of:
    </div>
    <div class="About_RowData">
      <asp:Label ID="lblAsOf" runat="server" Text="Dt"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="About_Row">
    <div class="About_RowLabel">
      Phone:
    </div>
    <div class="About_RowData">
      <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="Ph"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

all the `nth-` pseudo selectors work with sibling elements. That is, elements that share the same immediate parent.

All your `.About_RowLabel` are the first in their parent (the `.About_Row` element) so they are all odd.

Target the alternating parents

```
.About_Row:nth-of-type(odd) .About_RowLabel {
    background-color: #DEF3CA;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/o5dv4qkc/4/